# KNN algorithm: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, knn

i have not been using python for some time and having trouble finding the solution to this problem.
I tried to change the equation for euclidean distance function but it did not do any good. Maybe i am blind to see the solution to my problem.

Here is my code:

```
from math import sqrt
import csv
from random import shuffle
import numpy as np
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import operator
import math


iris = datasets.load_iris() 

X = iris.data
y = iris.target



def euclideanDistance(id1, id2):
    for x in range(len(id1)-1):
        dist = np.sqrt(np.sum((int(id2[x]) - int(id1[x]))**2))
    return dist

data1 = [2, 2, 2, 'a']
data2 = [4, 4, 4, 'b']
distance = euclideanDistance(data1, data2)
print(distance)

def mykNN(X, y, x_):
    distance = []
    neighbour = []

    for i in range(len(X)):
        d = euclideanDistance(X[i], x_ )
        distance.append((X[i], d))
    distance.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))

    for r in range(k):
        options.append(distance[r][0])
    options = neighbour
    return neighbour

k=3

y_ = mykNN(X, y,k)
print(y_)
```

no matter what how i change my function it comes up with this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-2a5bfc4a796d> in <module>
     42 k=3
     43 
---> 44 y_ = mykNN(X, y,k)
     45 print(y_)
     46 

<ipython-input-85-2a5bfc4a796d> in mykNN(X, y, x_)
     31 
     32     for i in range(len(X)):
---> 33         d = euclideanDistance(X[i], x_ )
     34         distance.append((X[i], d))
     35     distance.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))

<ipython-input-85-2a5bfc4a796d> in euclideanDistance(id1, id2)
     18 def euclideanDistance(id1, id2):
     19     for x in range(len(id1)-1):
---> 20         dist = np.sqrt(np.sum((int(id2[x]) - int(id1[x]))**2))
     21     return dist
     22 

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I would appreciate your response as this has been bothering me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error is telling you that in `euclideanDistance()`, either `id1` or `id2` (or both) is an integer, since those are the two identifiers you're indexing on that line. To follow it through:

- You set `k = 3`
- You call `mykNN(X, y, k)`, which means that in `mykNN()`, `x_ == 3`.
- You call `euclideanDistance(X[i], x_)`, which means that in `euclideanDistance()`, `id2 == 3`.
- You attempt to index `id2` on the indicated line. Integers can't be indexed, thus the exception.

So that's what caused your error. As I'm not sure exactly what your code is doing, I can't directly recommend a fix.